# Comparing hex number ranges for unicode encodings gives unexpected result

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm using UTF-8 encodings of Japanese Characters to distinguish so called Hiragana characters from Kanji characters in my script. The Unicode table for the relevant characters can be found [here](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml). As is evident from the table, the knji I want to identify are part of the last table called "CJK unifed ideographs - Common and uncommon kanji" and are in a number range of (4e00 - 9faf, Hexadeximal numbers). The undesired Hiragana and Katakana Characters are part of the lower numbers (3040-309f, 30a0 - 30ff).

So the idea is quite simple: Encode the first and last kanji characters from the kanji table by using UTF-8 encoding. That way they can be used for comparisons. You iterate over every character in a given string of Japanese characters, encode it using UTF-8 and then compare it to the interval of the kanji characters.

```py
def find_kanji(chars):
    
    min_char = '一'.encode('utf8')    
    max_char = '䶿'.encode('utf8')
    
    found = []
    for char in chars:
        if min_char <= char.encode('utf8') <= max_char:
             found.append(char)

    return found
```

However, this doesn't work, if I specify the full interval. It only works if the comparison is shortened to

```py
if min_char <= char.encode('utf8'):
```

I don't know how hexadecimal encoding of strings works and so I can't tell what the problem is exactly. For example, if I encode my characters, they return encodings such as

```
あ: b'\xe3\x81\x82'
お: b'\xe3\x81\x8a'
青: b'\xe9\x9d\x92'
い: b'\xe3\x81\x84'
```

and I can't really link an encoding such as `b'\xe9\x9d\x92'` to a Hex number in the table in the [link](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml). The character 青 has the encoding `b'\xe9\x9d\x92'`, yet in the table it is documented with the Hex number `9752` and I don't understand how to translate the one into the other. That's why I'm unable to determine why my number comparison fails.

Example code:

```py
def find_kanji(chars):
    
    min_char = '一'.encode('utf8')    
    max_char = '䶿'.encode('utf8')
    
    found = []
    for char in chars:
        if min_char <= char.encode('utf8') <= max_char: # remove comparison with max_char to make work
             found.append(char)

    return found

print(find_kanji('吸い込む'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this encoding business at all. Just compare unicode characters directly:

```
def find_kanji(chars):
    min_char = '\u4e00'
    max_char = '\u9faf'

    return [
        c for c in chars
        if min_char <= c <= max_char
    ]
```

Alternatively, consider using a range regular expression, or the `regex` module, which allows you to match unicode blocks directly.

Comment: I never knew you could just compare strings with each other, as in: even 'a' < 'b' is possible. My only questions would still be: Why are the encodings I get from python so different from those on the webpage? Are they different ways to write hex values? And: how does python know which numbers from which character table to use for comparison? If I do 'a' < 'b', does it use ASCII, or does it always use the UNICODE table?

Comment: 1) utf8 bytes are different from unicode character codes. utf8 is a variable length encoding, it can use up to 4 bytes to encode a single character.

Comment: 2) python strings (`str`) are unicode and use code points (=unicode character numbers) for comparisons.

Comment: if utf8 encodings contain multiple characters, then how does python even convert something like `b'\xe3\x81\x82'` into something which can do comparisons using "<" and ">"? I'm asking bc it is possible to do `b'\xe3\x81\x82' < b'\xe5\x81\x82'`, but it isn't possible to do `b'\xe3\x81\x82' > '\u3244'`. Whatever else I try to do with the utf8 encoding, I always get some kind of error. Either "not supported operand" during comparisons, or "invalid literal for int() with base 10" when I try to convert it to a regular number. What are the actual ints when doing `b'\xe3\x81\x82' < b'\xe5\x81\x82'`?

Comment: Encoding and unicode is a complex matter, but luckily pretty well documented, see for example https://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/